# Sorting on text field in solr

Tags: sorting, solr, solrcloud

I am using solr 3.4 and want to have solr search results to be sorted on text field. How can I achieve sorting on text field as with int natural ordering?

Is there any way to convert text field to int during query?

My sort field is of string type and I want it to be behave as int field while sorting. I can not change field type as the index size is too large and can not re index.

Any idea how can I achieve this?

Comment: Please give an example too. Do you want strings like `Ep 1, Ep 2, Ep 10` to be sorted by natural ordering?

Comment: No i have text field with values like 90,100,201 ect. i want these values to be sorted as int and not as string. case there sort order will be different in both the cases

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not very sure, but you can check for the [Function Queries](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/FunctionQuery) with functions like abs or any mathematical functions which might convert it to the int values and use it for sort

e.g. `abs(some_field) desc`

Else, copy the field into the new field with int type which would need reindex.

Also, Sorting doesn't work good on multivalued and tokenized Text fields.

[Documentation](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/CommonQueryParameters#sort) - 
Sorting can be done on the "score" of the document, or on any multiValued="false" indexed="true" field provided that field is either non-tokenized (ie: has no Analyzer) or uses an Analyzer that only produces a single Term (ie: uses the KeywordTokenizer)

Comment: This answer was very hekpful

Comment: No! abs can't be used on strng type. Solr will reoprt "unweighted use on abs(str(field name))... blah blah blah" error message.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to do it during the query.

You have to had [additional field](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/7_5/defining-fields.html) and [copying](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/7_5/copying-fields.html) the text field over the new integer field, then reindex your database.
Use a [filter](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/7_5/charfilterfactories.html) to be sure that the conversion will work.